# GeoJSON - Display all features in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to list all my features from a GeoJSON file in a table on a website and i am stuck figuring out how to achieve this.

As a first step i built a Leaflet map showing all locations loaded from the GeoJSON file which works pretty good.

What i would like to have in addition to the map is a rating system on a second page, which features all the locations from the GeoJSON in a table (I only need names for now, the rating system would be a different problem...).

Note that i am an absolute beginner and need a very detailed "tutorial" for this.

My GeoJSON looks like this:

```
   {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ x,y ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "FID":0,
    "Shape *":"Point",
    "Name":"XXX",
    "Ditrict":"Dist1",
    "Str_No":"Street 1",
    "ZIP":"Some ZIP",
    "Phone":"Some Number",
    "Rating":4.5
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ x,y ]
    }, and so on
```

I hope that there is a simple solution for this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GeoJSON object is `var geoJSON`, you can get all the names for each feature by doing the following:

```
var featureNames = [];

for (var i = 0; i < geoJSON.features.length; i++) {
  var currentFeature = geoJSON.features[i];

  var featureName = currentFeature.properties.Name;
  var featureId = currentFeature.properties.FID;

  console.log(featureName);
  featureNames.push({ featureId: featureId, featureName : featureName });
}
```

So `featureNames` will have each `feature` object with it's name in an array.

To put them all in a table, I'm going to use [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/). If I have a `<div id="myTable">`, then:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "title": "Feature Names", "targets": 0 }
  ]
  data: featureNames,
  scrollY: 300,
  paging: false
} );
```